# How to use another default_head_blocks.xml for a specific template?

Tags: magento2, layout

My theme 'theme1' has Blank as parent.

I created a page_layout called landing in `app\design\frontend\me\theme1\Magento_Theme\page_layout\landing.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
    <container name="root">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Magento_Theme::html/landing.phtml"></block>
    </container>
    <referenceContainer name="page.main.title" remove="true"/>
</layout>
```

I don't want to load the same head block for this layout. How do you tell Magento to load let say `app\design\frontend\me\theme1\Magento_Theme\layout\landing_head_blocks.xml` ?

Comment: you can override xml  inside your theme and changes as per your requiements

Comment: I don't have to override the default head blocks, I want to have different head blocks for this specific page_layout.

Answer (score 0):

You can update the file as below:

```
app\design\frontend\me\theme1\Magento_Theme\layout\head.xml
```